# How add View in Android module in Tintaium

Tags: titanium-modules, titanium-proxy

i just Novice to Android module development with Titanium.

I want to add simple View in android module and in Titanium android Application on button click i just want to open that View .

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

For creating view in titanium android module just check this [link](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/moddevguide/mobile/android/src/ti/moddevguide) and check `DemoView.java` and `DemoViewProxy.java`. ANd please suffix should be the same else it will consider it a view.

Then you can require your module in titanium and create a view like this:

```
var view = module.createDemoView({
left:0,
width:320,
top:0,
height:480
});
win.add(view);
```